# What does "*" (asterisk) mean in RFC?

Tags: http, rfc

Quote from [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987#section-3.2.1：](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987#section-3.2.1%EF%BC%9A)

> In order to include character set and language information, this
> specification modifies the RFC 2616 grammar to be:
>
> ```
>  parameter     = reg-parameter / ext-parameter
>
>  reg-parameter = parmname LWSP "=" LWSP value
>
>  ext-parameter = parmname "*" LWSP "=" LWSP ext-value
>
>  parmname      = 1*attr-char
>
>  ext-value     = charset  "'" [ language ] "'" value-chars
>                ; like RFC 2231's <extended-initial-value>
>                ; (see [RFC2231], Section 7)
>
>  charset       = "UTF-8" / "ISO-8859-1" / mime-charset
>
>  mime-charset  = 1*mime-charsetc
> ```

What does `*` mean in `parmname      = 1*attr-char`? And also the same question at `mime-charset  = 1*mime-charsetc`.

What I have known is that `"*"` mean exactly `*` itself in `ext-parameter = parmname "*" LWSP "=" LWSP ext-value`, due to the fact that the RFC show an example latter of `ext-parameter = parmname "*" LWSP "=" LWSP ext-value`:

> title*=iso-8859-1'en'%A3%20rates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a quantifier that describes the valid number of repetitions.

> "1*element" requires at least one element.

See [RFC 2616 section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.1) - Augmented BNF:

```
*rule
      The character "*" preceding an element indicates repetition. The
      full form is "<n>*<m>element" indicating at least <n> and at most
      <m> occurrences of element. Default values are 0 and infinity so
      that "*(element)" allows any number, including zero; "1*element"
      requires at least one; and "1*2element" allows one or two.
```

Answer (score 1):

The spec you quoted says:

> This specification uses the ABNF (Augmented Backus-Naur Form)
> notation defined in [RFC5234].  The following core rules are included
> by reference, as defined in [RFC5234], Appendix B.1: ALPHA (letters),
> DIGIT (decimal 0-9), HEXDIG (hexadecimal 0-9/A-F/a-f), and LWSP
> (linear whitespace).

Go to RFC 5234 and you'll find https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#section-3.6